# Shopify Dawn Theme, Edit Specific Products/ Collection

Tags: shopify, product, price, shopify-template

I need to customize a Shopify Webshop, the task is to hide the Prices on B2B Products, these are on a seperate Page.

I found multiple solutions to hide Prices but they all get applied on the whole shop.

Maybe somebody can Help, Thank You all in Advance!

I tried via CSS, the Shopify Editor, some custom Liquid Code.

https://help.groupthought.com/article/982-hide-the-price-for-certain-products-only-in-collection-grid-view

This solution would be perfect, but unfortunately its outdated.

Comment: use this snipet inside price.liquid https://prnt.sc/SGCg4-pQgjf-

Comment: then use it {% unless no_price %}  {%endunless %}

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree, attached solution is old but you can still use this Logic.

**Step : 1**

Add any specific tag to you B2B Products. For example : `hide-price` or `no-price` tag into your product.

[image]

**Step : 2**

I'm using ***Dawn*** as a demo theme.

Inside Dawn, Let's say, I want to hide price inside featured collection section. For that, there is `card-product.liquid` snippet, where I've added hide-price logic. (See below SS)

You can use the same logic for Product page too.

[image]

**Output**

[image]